# Lie algebras and LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I am writing in LaTeX some theorems in which the symbols of Lie Algebras are used. What is the command in LaTeX for the symbol of a Lie algebra *g* of a Lie group *G*?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: It is `\mathfrak{g}`. The font `\mathfrak` is a part of the package `amsfonts`.